# Does clang on Mac not support uniform initialization?

Tags: c++, macos

Is clang on Mac not support uniform initialization?

I tried compiling following code, But compiler raise a error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {3, 1, 9, 4};
    std::cout << v[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Error:

```
vector.cpp:9:22: error: non-aggregate type 'std::vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
    std::vector<int> v = {3, 1, 9, 4};
                     ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

OS: macOS 10.12.4

compiler version:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: You should *always* include any compiler errors in your question (verbatim).

Comment: Make sure that the code actually is compiled with c++11, i.e. in your build settings, check that "c++ Language Dialect" is set to `C++11`, which then means compiler flag "-std=c++1" to be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you are *not* compiling the code as C++11/14 (`-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`)? If not; do that. Clang *does* support what you are trying to do.