# Can't assign value to vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign value to a vector but I keep getting different errors. I am using clang++ version 14.0.0 to build the file and I am getting the error using vs code debugger.

Here are the different erros:

When i run this code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    
    v = {0, 1};

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error "expected expression".

When i run this code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    
    v = vector<int>{0, 1};

    return 0;
}
```

I get error "expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction"

Neither initiliazing nor assigning the vector later seems to work.

If my problem is unclear. Please let me know how I can improve :)

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem, [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/YvxxvEKzn), are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: What version of compilator do you have? have you add any "-std" flag?

Comment: [I can't replicate the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/7eWfaKxzr). Are you sure you use Clang 14? What flags and options do you use to build? How do you build?

Comment: See dupe(with same problem): [Does clang on Mac not support uniform initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571021/does-clang-on-mac-not-support-uniform-initialization)

Comment: None of your examples use initialization. This would be initialization: `vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clang++` on Mac defaults to using C++98 (`-std=c++98`) and in C++98 both errors are to be expected.

Just add

```
-std=c++11
```

(or later, like `-std=c++14`, `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++20`) when compiling and both your snippets will compile fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! If anybody wonders how to do this in VS Code, just add "-std=c++11" to the args list in "tasks.json" file.